# How can I count the number of times that different PDF files are accessed in an Apache log file?

Tags: command-line

I have a log file which contains traffic for an entire server. The server serves multiple domains, but I know that all of the PDF files I want to count are in /some/directory/.

I know that I can get a list of all the PDF files I want if I grep that directory for the 'pdf' extension.

How can I then count how many times each PDF was accessed individually from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bit longer than one line but it will give you a better summary. You can modify this with the path to the pdfs and the apache access_log file and just paste it in to the command line or put it in a bash script

```
 for file in `ls /path/to/pdfs | grep pdf `
 do
  COUNT=`grep -c $file access_log`
  echo $file $COUNT
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep for the name of the pdf file in your log and use the `-c` option to count occurrences. For example:

```
grep -c myfile.pdf apache.log
```

---

If you have hundreds of files, create a single file with a list of all the filenames, e.g.

```
$ cat filelist.txt

foo.pdf
bar.pdf
```

and then use grep in a loop

```
while read filename
do 
   COUNT=$(grep -c $filename apache.log) 
   echo $filename:$COUNT 
done < filelist.txt
```

This will print out how many times each pdf file occurred in the log.

Comment: I need to find about 100 individual PDF files, and get statistics for them individually.

Answer (score -2):

Use `grep` to identify the rows with your pdf and then `wc -l` to count the rows found:

```
grep /your/pdf logfile | wc -l
```

You may also check for 200 responses wrt 302 - i.e. if the user has only accessed a page or the full document (some pdf readers only load a page at a time)

Comment: Sorry, this is not useless, as it works. Your solution of `grep -c` is more elegant.